# Cannot install external package insde python when uwsgi run

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I run a Python application within uwsgi, and then my application is trying to install an external package with this code:

`subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", module])`

But there is an error:

> unable to load configuration from pip

This is my uwsgi configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
module = bin.run:app
manage-script-name = true
virtualenv = venv
master = true
processes = 5
http-socket = 0.0.0.0:9002
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
enable-threads=true
lazy=true
```

How can I fix this? Ive tried with `flask run` and it worked normally.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `sys.executable` isn't `python` like it normally would be. It points to the `uwsgi` executable instead. So your code is actually trying to start up another `uwsgi` process.

The first argument of `uwsgi` is a configuration file to load from (https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html#ini-files).

> For convenience, uWSGI recognizes bare .ini arguments specially, so the invocation uwsgi myconf.ini is equal to uwsgi --ini myconf.ini

Since the first argument that you gave uwsgi is `pip`, it tries to load a file called `pip`, can't, and then dies.

For me, hard coding "python" (or "python3" if that's where it is on your system) as the executable to run fixed it.